# nested mouseover not working

Tags: nested, mouseover

This works in FF but not I.E.  The mouseover on the a tag won't activate. I want to be able to set the class for the a tag when user mouse over it.

```
 <div class="selects-options" id="dropsort"
                       onmouseover="divshowsort();"
                       style="position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 1px; width: 153px;display:none;"
                       onmouseout="hidesort();">
                     <div class="drop-holder">
                        <div class="drop-list">
                           <ul>
                              <li class="items_selected" id="li1" rel="0">
                                 <a onmouseover="sortclass('li1');"
                                    onclick="divhidesort('R');" href="#">
                                    <span>Relevance</span>
                                 </a>
                              </li>
                              <li class="" id="li2" rel="1">
                                 <a onmouseover="sortclass('li2');"
                                    onclick="divhidesort('A');" href="#">
                                    <span>Title A-Z</span>
                                 </a>
                              </li>
                              <li class="" id="li3" rel="2">
                                 <a onmouseover="sortclass('li3');"
                                    onclick="divhidesort('D');" href="#">
                                    <span>Newest</span>
                                 </a>
                              </li>
                           </ul>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: You should also post the JavaScript functions (sortclass, divshowsort, hidesort...).

Comment: @Seza        
function divshowsort() {
         document.getElementById("dropsort").style.display = "inline";
         document.getElementById("sortsel").setAttribute("class", "sortselc");
         }

Comment: @Seza function sortclass(sortid) {
         document.getElementById("li1").setAttribute("class", "");
         document.getElementById("li2").setAttribute("class", "");
         document.getElementById("li3").setAttribute("class", "");
         document.getElementById(sortid).setAttribute("class", "items-selected");

         }